# Animating objects inside JavaFX 2D Game

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, 2d-games

I'm going to build a simple online 2D `game` using JavaFX. but i have a question regarding animating graphic objects inside it . for example if a have a vector for "person" and want a move his hand only , Should i redraw many sprites for this movement ? and play an animation for replacing the image quickly ?

Almost I know that way . but what i want to know is there another way instead redrawing many images for one movement?

What i mean is there a way for moving the hand only freely for same image ? and If i'm using Inkscape and has exported the image as fx. does it help to do that ?

Your tips please , i'm new to this field

Comment: I'm not sure what "exported the image as fx" means.  JavaFX 2+ does not have any proprietary image format.

Comment: I meant exporting image as fx using software like Inkscape

Comment: There is no such thing as fx to export to.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the [obsolete JavaFX script language](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX_Script) which is no longer used in modern [JavaFX 8 implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).

Answer (score 2):

- Use [inverse kinematics](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics) for [JavaFX](http://blog.netopyr.com/2013/03/06/javafx-library-for-inverse-kinematics-2-0/) for animating rigged vectors.
- Use [sprite animation](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-sprite-animation-with-javafx/) for animating bitmapped images.
- Use [fbx](https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/fbx-importer/blob/master/README.md) for animating 3D models.

Comment: Thx jewelsea , but what's the ideal and professional method for 2D ? inverse or sprite ?

Comment: There is no ideal methods.  There are just different techniques to use depending upon what you are doing and the art assets and skills you have.